# Reduce an array of Result in Swift

Tags: swift

Let's assume a function is called when mapping an array, and this function returns a `Result`. For example:

```
func parseFeedItem(_ object: Any) -> Result<FeedItem, Error> {...}

func parseFeed(_ root: Any) -> Result<Feed, Error> {
    ...
    let items = objects.compactMap { parseFeedItem($0) }
    ...
}
```

The result of the map (`items` above), will be an array of `Result`s. Ideally, following this, we'd want to know the "union" of results, that is a `Result` as either:

- `success` with an array of values, if all `Result`s in the array are `success`es; or
- `failure` with the error of the first `failure` in the array.

Basically, I came up with:

```
typealias Results<T, E> = Result<[T], E> where E: Error

let r: Results<FeedItem, Error> = items.reduce(.success([FeedItem]())) { (accumulator, result) -> Results<FeedItem, Error> in
    switch accumulator {
    case .failure(_):
        return accumulator
    case .success(let array):
        switch result {
        case .failure(let error):
            return .failure(error)
        case .success(let value):
            var newArray = array
            newArray.append(value)
            return .success(newArray)
        }
    }
}
```

For example, if run with only `success`es:

```
let items: [Result<FeedItem, Error>] = [
    .success(FeedItem(1)),
    .success(FeedItem(2)),
    .success(FeedItem(3)),
]
... run `reduce` defined above ...
print(r) // .success([FeedItem(1), FeedItem(2), FeedItem(3)])
```

And if the array contains at least one `failure`, like:

```
let items: [Result<FeedItem, Error>] = [
    .success(FeedItem(1)),
    .success(FeedItem(2)),
    .failure(MyError.blah),
]
... run `reduce` defined above ...
print(r) // .failure(MyError.blah)
```

So this works. However, here are the questions:

- is there a shorter way to do this?
- is it performant, i.e. is there any way this could be improved?

Comment: Maybe you should post this at https://codereview.stackexchange.com since you don't have an issue with your code.

Comment: Didn't know about codereview.stackexchange.com. Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 3):

There is a shorter and generic way to accomplish this.
The Result type has two very useful methods: [map()](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/result/3139400-map) and [flatMap()](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/result/3139395-flatmap), see the linked Apple documentation to know exactly how they work.

Using them I built this generic function that allows you to perform custom operations between types wrapped in a Result, giving .success (and the result of the operation) if both the members of the operation are a success, or failure the first time it encounters an error :

```
func resultOperation<T, E: Error>(_ lhs: Result<T, E>, _ rhs: Result<T, E>, _ operation: ((T, T) -> T)) -> Result<T, E> {
    lhs.flatMap { (lhsValue) -> Result<T, E> in
        rhs.map { (rhsValue) -> T in
            return operation(lhsValue, rhsValue)
        }
    }
}
```

In your case the operation parameter would be the + operator, which adds the elements of two arrays in a single array. The code would look like:

```
let r: Results<FeedItem, Error> = items.reduce(.success([FeedItem]())) { resultOperation($0, $1, +) }
```